# Functional Testing in Java

Tags: java, testing, junit, integration-testing

I believe functional testing is testing of two or more modules together with the intent of finding defects, demonstrating that defects are not present, and verifying that the module performs its intended functions. 
Is there any functional testing tool for java applications? I'm in need to do this. I know of junit which I have used in unit testing and also T2 utility which is an extension of junit, which I have used for automated testing. Is there any particular framework or tool for functional testing?

Comment: Actually what you're describing is called integration testing. Functional testing is also known as acceptance testing (making sure that the system does what the customer expects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUnit is more aimed at unit testing. For functional testing, take a look at [TestNG](http://testng.org), which offers advanced functional testing features such as:

- Groups.
- Testing multithreaded code.
- Runs in parallel.
- Dependencies.
- Suite-level configurations.
- Dependency injection (Guice).

Answer (score 0):

Largely the same sets of tools, although how you test might be a little different.

I consider a lot of functional and integration testing to be sort-of the same thing. As such I'll use more BDD-oriented tools, like [easyb](http://mockito.org/) or [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/) instead of "raw" JUnit or TestNG.

Depending on what functionality you're testing, mocking libraries like [mockito](http://mockito.org/) or [powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) are handy, although perhaps not as much as with "pure" unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

With introduction of Junit4, you can do functional testing of Java using Junit as well.
The latest junit 4 version (junit 4.11) comes with some very good features like parametrization, annonation support and annonations like @Ignore, exception test support, suite configuration, etc.
But off-course you'll have to do little bit modification to handle the default fatal behavior of assertions. You can refer http://apitestingwithjunit.blogspot.in/ on how to achieve this (don't worry it is very simple).